# update_post_meta() adding bits in database

Tags: post-meta

I'm adding a bulk of custom meta data in one go from a form in the frontend.

```
$youtube = 'a:5:{s:10:"video_type";s:7:"youtube";s:16:"videopress_group";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:22:"videopress_youtube_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";s:23:"videopress_external_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";s:17:"videopress_upload";s:0:"";s:16:"videopress_embed";s:1:"0";s:19:"videopress_download";s:1:"0";}}s:13:"youtube_group";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:19:"youtube_youtube_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws82rXrjBOI";s:16:"youtube_controls";s:1:"1";s:17:"youtube_suggested";s:1:"1";}}s:11:"vimeo_group";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:8:"vimeo_id";s:8:"";s:14:"vimeo_portrait";s:1:"1";s:11:"vimeo_title";s:1:"1";s:12:"vimeo_byline";s:1:"1";}}s:12:"twitch_group";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"twitch_url";s:34:"";s:18:"twitch_stream_from";s:10:"2016-08-03";}}}';
    update_post_meta($pid, 'video_options', $youtube, false);
```

But in the data base it's showing up as :

```
s:810:"a:5:{s:10:"video_type";s:7:"youtube";s:16:"videopress_group";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:22:"videopress_youtube_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";s:23:"videopress_external_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";s:17:"videopress_upload";s:0:"";s:16:"videopress_embed";s:1:"0";s:19:"videopress_download";s:1:"0";}}s:13:"youtube_group";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:19:"youtube_youtube_url";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws82rXrjBOI";s:16:"youtube_controls";s:1:"1";s:17:"youtube_suggested";s:1:"1";}}s:11:"vimeo_group";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:8:"vimeo_id";s:8:"77091919";s:14:"vimeo_portrait";s:1:"1";s:11:"vimeo_title";s:1:"1";s:12:"vimeo_byline";s:1:"1";}}s:12:"twitch_group";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"twitch_url";s:34:"http://www.twitch.tv/kinggothalion";s:18:"twitch_stream_from";s:10:"2016-08-03";}}}";
```

Where is that S:810:" coming from?

Comment: You should read about [String serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) and [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). And you should not provide a serialized string, but an object or an array to the `update_post_meta()` function. It will serialize it by itself.

Comment: s:810 defines that your serialized form of data has 810 character

Answer (score 1):

WP serialises the data for you into a single meta field. It's serialised the data you had already serialised. You need to add the data in the form that you'd like it when you read it again.